# Ajax file upload With ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax, file-upload

Has anybody any help with using this control( http://www.phpletter.com/Demo/AjaxFileUpload-Demo/ ) with ASP.NET MVC
I've tried, but in my controller the HttpPostedFile is always null.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase file) { ... }
```

Comment: I get the result file is null

Answer (score 0):

```
in View   <input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#formname").bind("submit", function () {

        var ext = $('#file').val().split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
        if (ext != "") {
            if ($.inArray(ext, ['gif', 'png', 'bmp', 'jpg', 'jpeg']) == -1) {
                alert('Invalid file extension!');
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

in Controller

```
 public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
 string fileName = "";
  if (file != null)
  {
    if (file.ContentLength > 0)
                        {
                            fileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);

                            string filePath = Path.Combine(HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/FileFolder"), fileName);
                            file.SaveAs(filePath);
                        }
                    }
}
```